# Not all Site Columns gets crawled properly

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property

According to [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136%28v=office.15%29.aspx) all site columns should become Managed Properties. I am currently experiencing a problem with my search service application. When I go to "Managed Properties" under the search service application I cannot find all Site Columns that came with my Feature as Managed Properties. They allready contain Information and Index Reset with a Full Crawl afterwards didn't help (tried a view times over days). The columns get crawled for sure because they all are listed under craweld Properties. 
Only 5 of them became Managed Properties

[image: All Craweled Properties that should have became Managed Properties]

I don't know what the problem could be. If needed I can post sample code on how the Search Service Application was set up (Powershell) or XML of a field Definition, or anything.

**Edit**
Tested my Solution in an other Enviroment and discovered that the Columns may not be crawled for real. The Problem is certainly not caused by the Type of the Columns.
in the Enviroment i need the columns there are just the ones like `ows_Name` but not those who start like `ows_r_FOURLETTERCODE_Name`|`ows_q_FOURLETTERCODE_Name`. But just those with the four-letter-code in them are automatically connected as managed properties.

here a picture of the managed properties of the other enviroment mentioned:
[image: some of the managed properties in the dev enviroment]

**Edit**
I tried to reinstall the Search Service Application. It was definitely not the problem. The Search Service Application is working fine!

Comment: SharePoint will create managed porperties for all types of columns, as stated in the link I have provided. I also proved the solution on a other dev enviroment, where the managed properties were created.. 
The difference is that on the one enviroment all properties are created and on the other one just those with the `ows_` prefix but not `ows_r/q/taxid_4LETTERCODE_` prefix

Answer (score 0):

We ended up by setting up a new SharePoint Farm and migrated the content. There were a few corrupt Solutions and issues with the Search Service Accounts. We don't have these problems anymore